How are Mean Well OEM power supplies mounted?
I'm planning to use Mean Well LRS-75 type of power supplies inside a cabinet. I think they are categorized as chassis mount type not DIN rail type.
How are these supplies in practice mounted on? On a custom made aluminium plate? I want to mount such supplies next to each other on a plate but cannot find enough info or examples how to mount them on a plate ect.
Would be glad if anybody has practical experience.
Added some photos from this site:



You didn't mention the make or model anywhere in your question so I've fixed that. Add a photo so that users don't have to click a link to understand your question.

I added some photos.

that side plate tends to get hot, so use a conductive material or mount it from the "bottom" plate if you're going to be drawing more than 25W from it. I would also suggest a slight angle, "leaning over the cliff" to improve natural convection compares to a plumb mount. If you can standoff the back from the mounting surface, that too helps thermals a bit. If you need >50W, use the LRS-150/200 line of passive-cooled PSUs.

@dandavis It is written "cooling by free air convection" in the datasheet. Doesn't it already mean passive-cooled PSU?

yes, all the LRS series are passive-cooled; i meant you could still upgrade to a stronger supply with a lower utilization w/o a fan if your enclosure is toasty.

Page 4 of the datasheet you linked shows the positions and sizes of all screw holes. Drill matching holes into your enclosure and screw it into those. For large-volume production, you can stamp the holes into the enclosure during manufacture.

You mean screw drills from the button of the PSU? I though I could use L brackets. Can u see any size for the bottom screws? Im afraid to damage the PCB.

@GNZ No, the PSU already has those holes, in positions marked on the datasheet. I'm saying drill holes into the enclosure you plan to mount the PSU into.

So there are two types of mounting? One from the bottom one from the side with L brackets?

@GNZ I would mount it from the bottom, and only add side mounting if it was necessary, if you don't already have a side wall to mount to. Though be aware that these power supplies are not touch-safe, and are not intended to be mounted outside of a fully enclosed enclosure, as it sounds like you're trying to do.

I plan to mount it on aluminium plate and earth ground the supply chassis through the aluminium plate(connects to mains earth) .

@GNZ As long as it's properly grounded (make sure to check that that counts!) and the terminals are blocked in such a way that a careless user couldn't accidentally touch exposed mains voltage, you should be fine. Just make sure you guard against accidental contact.

@GNZ There are rules how you must install the earth wire - you likely need to bond it directly to metal chassis in an approved way for your electrical code. Then you can bolt aluminium plate to that metal chassis, and then bolt the PSU to aluminium. However, aluminium oxidizes easily and makes poor contact. And you also must use another earth wire from the metal chassis to PSU earth screw (third pin from left).

@GNZ The data sheet says the screws are M3, and the bottom ones specifically say length = 3.0 (millimetres).  Or you can use the side screw holes, also marked M3, length = 5.

@SimonB But for the bottom if I use a plate should I account for the thickness of the plate for the screw length? I dont want to damage the PCB

@GNZ - yes, if the plate is thick, you'll need slightly longer screws.


Image taken from OnShape model LRS-75 Mean Well by atant1.

(1) and (2) allow screw or self-tapper mount of large side directly to panel.
(3) and (4) allow screw or self-tapper mount of narrow side to panel.
(5), (6), (7) and (8) are M3 tapped holes and allow mounting to a panel or bracket from the rear using M3 screws. Screws must be the correct length to avoid reaching the PCB or internal components.

